# where should I add module dependencies in mean.js (for ng-sortable)

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I am trying to add ng-sortable to my mean.js based app. https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable

Following the install instructions and adapting them to mean.js I included the js and css files (which are loading correctly), but where I fall down is adding module dependencies:

> And Inject the sortable module as dependency.
>
> ```
> angular.module('xyzApp', ['ui.sortable', '....']);
> ```

My angularjs controller  looks like this:

```
var listers_mod = angular.module('listers');
listers_mod.controller('PagesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location',  'Authentication',
    function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, Authentication) { ... }
]);
```

My first  attempt was to add the ui.sortable in the controller file above:

```
var listers_mod = angular.module('listers', ['ui.sortable']);
```

Obviously this did not work.  As you can probably tell I am very new to mean.js and the MEAN stack in general so I am stumbling around blind on this one.  I tried googling around and of course searching here, but I didn't find any answers that made any sense to me.

Any help welcome.

Comment: why did that not work? it looks like you injected it correctly into your module...

Comment: @AndrewCounts Not sure, no fail message, but the whole module I attach it wont even run anymore with it there. The pages related to the module and menu items all disapear, and only come back if I remove it.

Comment: no errors in the console log?

Comment: @AndrewCounts no errors at all either when watching the server output or in the console log.  Just gone :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I add a new Angular module to a mean.js based application, I add the module to the `config.js` file within the `public` directory.  There is a list of module dependencies which you can add to as you add more modules to your project:

Link to source:
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/f4b62ca8199227c6791d535bbf67bba5d2db91f0/public/config.js#L7

Example:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils'];
```

Try adding it there instead of using the `var listers_mod = angular.module('listers');` line you have in your controller.  You may not need to inject it into your controller at all -- looking at the documentation you could just try accessing it in the HTML code after you've added it to your application's module list.

Comment: thanks. I just realised this myself and was about to answer my own question when I noticed you had already got there already :).

Answer (score 3):

Base on dylants's answer, found the configuration file path has been changed to this file

modules/core/client/app/config.js

I'm using meanjs-version 0.4.2, adding the new module into applicationModuleVendorDependencies works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can put dependencies as a second parameter of ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule function.

Example, put timer in your module:

public/modules/your-module/your-module.client.module.js:

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('your-moduler', ['timer']);
```