# Where should I add module dependencies for ng-sortable in mean.js

Tags: angularjs, json, jquery-ui, mean-stack, ng-sortable

I have this problem: [where should I add module dependencies in mean.js (for ng-sortable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139385/where-should-i-add-module-dependencies-in-mean-js-for-ng-sortable)

One answer to this question was to add this code-line in the config.js file:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate',
'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ui.sortable'];
```

The problem is that I don't have a config.js file. Instead I have a config.json file. My question is how I could do the corresponding action in my config.json?

Comment: So where did you learn about this `config.json` ? I don't any `config.js` in http://meanjs.org/docs.html either.

Comment: Sorry forgot the link, added it now @TJ